# How to break out of many functions, loops etc and start it again from beginning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, break

Let's have:

```
def foo():
    if x:
        do_something()
        if y:
             break_out_of_everything()
        else:
             do_something_2() 
    else:
        do_something_else()
```

How do I make a function `break_out_of_everything()` that will exit the whole foo() function and start it again?

Comment: Does it have to be a function? Then only exceptions have that behaviour. Otherwise, just `return`.

Comment: or a while loop.. `while breaker == False` .... `if y: breaker = True; break`. But refactoring it to a form where you can just `return` is for sure more elegant

Comment: you may want to use a decorator.

Answer (score 1):

**This is perfect solution right for you.**

[python-goto](https://github.com/snoack/python-goto)

Try out quick example, and you can use it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Will your function eventually be returning a value and is the issue just that it's dependent on a specific attribute that will eventually change and make `foo()` work correctly? If so, you can just recursively call your function, but you need to make sure that the code will eventually hit a different return statement and that it wont just keep calling `foo()` over and over again

```
import time

def foo():
    if x:
        do_something()
        if y:
             time.sleep(5)
             return foo()
        else:
             do_something_2() 
    else:
        do_something_else()
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def foo():
    if x:
        do_something()
        if y:
             foo()
        else:
             do_something_2() 
    else:
        do_something_else()
```

Comment: This wont work because it will never reach the return statement

Comment: Just need to make sure it eventually hits another return statement otherwise it will be an infinite recursive loop

Comment: @AK47 If both of x and y are True, it will be an infinite recursive loop, with return or without it